# Calculate product in Java, term vs. a 'for' loop, different results

Tags: java, for-loop

Consider:

```
    long y = 1;
    for (int i = 49; i > 43; i--) {
        y*= i;
    }

    long x = 49*48*47*46*45*44; // = 1478412928
    long y                      // = 10068347520
```

Why are the results different although the calculation is even?

Is there an explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`49*48*47*46*45*44` is a multiplication of `int` literals, and therefore performs `int` multiplications resulting in an `int` value. It overflows in this case (since the result is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) before you assign the result to the `long` variable. Hence the result is incorrect.

Change it to `49L*48*47*46*45*44` or `(long)49*48*47*46*45*44` to perform `long` multiplication.

In your first calculation, on the other hand, you begin with a `long` variable whose value is `1`, and the loop multiplies that `long` with an `int` in each iteration, performing `long` multiplication, so there's no overflow.